# Vertica DB returns different data formats for different technologies

Tags: python, r, vertica

Currently, I'm trying to migrate a process from R to Python. 
When I'm trying to verify the data pulled from vertica db, I notice that R and Python have returned me different date results(Logically the same date and time, but by value, it's different), and this will create hindrances in my migration, is there a reason for this conversion without me doing any changes to the result?
Ex query:

```
Select enddatetime from A where B="this"
```

Output from R Language:

```
6/9/2017  10:44:34 PM
```

Output from Python:

```
2017-06-09 12:14:33.866000-05:00
```

-05:00 denotes the difference from US time to GMT time,
And since I live in India, the difference between India and GMT is -05:30,hence total difference is 10:30 hrs. thereby making both the output logically correct, but the value differs.

Is there any way for me to get the Python output to correspond with the R output?

Comment: What does vsql return whith the same select? Which data type has been used for the source column? How did you run the select (R and Python code)?

Answer (score 1):

There is a difference between the data type stored in Vertica, and the formatting used by default by your language (R or Python) to display its value.

Each language maps the Vertica data type to its own data type. Python is most likely using the [datetime](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html) one.

When displaying a datetime variable, Python is using a default formater, but you can specify your own format, matching the R one, using the [date.strftime](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html) function. Ex :

```
d.strftime("%d/%m/%y")
```